# Slow Loading of images into Galleryview and app gets stuck while scrolling

Tags: android

I want to load the High Quality images into GalleryView using the Adapter mentioned below

I am also using the Universal Image Loader class and some other classes like FileCache,MemoryCache but still My images are loading very slowly in my GalleryView.

By observations I understood that images I am loading are very high resolution,I tried with scaling images like below

```
       final int REQUIRED_SIZE=150; instead of    
       final int REQUIRED_SIZE=HomeActivity.width;//scaling upto device width so that I can get high quality images



int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
    int scale=1;
    while(true){
        if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp/=2;
        height_tmp/=2;
        scale*=2;
    }
```

Please suggest for fast loading of High Quality images in my GalleryView

My Adapter:

```
     private ImageLoaderNew imageLoader;

          imageLoader = new ImageLoaderNew(getApplicationContext());

     public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
                private List<String>galleriesadp = new ArrayList<String>();
                int resId;
                private LayoutInflater inflater;
                Context context;

                public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<String> galleriesadp){
                    super(context, resId, galleriesadp);
                    this.resId = resId;
                    this.context=context;
                    this.galleriesadp=galleriesadp;
                }
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent123) {
//              

View v = convertView;
                Log.e("postion >>>",""+position);

                    LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                     View   itemView = inflator.inflate(resId, null);





                     ImageView image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                     image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);






                     try{
                         imageLoader .DisplayImg( galleriesadp.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), image);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    return itemView;

                }   
            }
```

My Image Loader class :

```
     public class ImageLoaderNew {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    public static Drawable d ;
    Context c;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoaderNew(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        this.c=context;
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

//    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
         memoryCache.put(url, getBitmap(url));
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {

              Log.e("bitmap_width",""+bitmap.getWidth());

              Log.e("bitmap_height",""+bitmap.getHeight());

//            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void DisplayImageNew(String url,ImageView imageView, RelativeLayout rlayout)
    {
        memoryCache.put(url, getBitmap(url));
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            d = new BitmapDrawable(c.getResources(),bitmap);

             rlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
//            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    public void DisplayImg(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap( bitmap, 0,70,70));



            Log.v("first", "first");
        }
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            Log.v("second", "second");

        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }//Lalit

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=HomeActivity.width;

            //Testing

              Log.e("device width",""+HomeActivity.width);

              Log.e("bitmap width",""+o.outWidth);

              Log.e("bitmap height",""+o.outHeight);



            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels,int width,int height) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

//  public void DisplayImage(String replaceAll, ImageView img) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      
//  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will usually happens when you load the image from the server. Best solution i found so far, is to use AQuery. In aQuery , you dont need to worry about memory cache,it willl load image without any interruption.Please refer this Link

Visit http://code.google.com/p/android-query/?

You can refer here also

[android lazy loading not showing images on phone or showing and is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092682/android-lazy-loading-not-showing-images-on-phone-or-showing-and-is-slow?rq=1)

Comment: if you need any help regarding aQuery, i shall always be here for you