# displaying image in the imageview directly from the internet

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to load an image which is located at the `url` "http://www.Karnatakatourism.org/mm/slide/chickmaglur_home.jpg" onto the `imageview` in `Android`.

Can anyone help me with the code to do the same?

Comment: Refer this [load image using Aquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092682/android-lazy-loading-not-showing-images-on-phone-or-showing-and-is-slow/18416212#18416212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use android query lib. http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

You just need to write

```
aq.id(R.id.imageview_profilee).image("your path");
```

Comment: even you don't need to write this code in AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one...

There many libs to do this, You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Here an example of usage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.karnatakatourism.org/mm/slide/chickmaglur_home.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Or you can use [Universal Image Loader class](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

in which you can use by this one.

```
 imageLoader.displayImage("http://www.karnatakatourism.org/mm/slide/chickmaglur_home.jpg", imageView, options);
```

Comment: Yes you have to. And you can also use AsyncTask also.